# Unable to login into the application on Jmeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter

I'm trying to build a login script for my website load testing on Jmeter, but I am not able to do so. I have added the cookie manager and cache manager too. I already recorded the script through http script recorder and made a transaction of the same and running test on this recorded scripts. The website is using spring security for login security.I tried to add Beanshell Preprocessor into the login sameple request for gzip deflate and passed the form parameters but still the server is not authenticating the request.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your login request doesn't work due to missing or improperly implemented [**correlation**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start).

Modern web applications widely use dynamic tokens for various reasons starting from client-side state tracking like [JSESSIONID](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/what-is-jsessionid-in-j2ee-web.html) and ending up with security mechanisms like [CSRF](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf)

The easiest way of identifying dynamic parameters is recording your test scenario one more time and comparing resulting [.jmx scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan). All parameters which will be different are a subject to correlation, to wit you need to:

1. Extract them from the previous response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
2. Replace recorded hard-coded values with the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from step 1

More information: [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)